# How can I make a SIMPLE net core authentication api using Angular?

Tags: sql, angular, asp.net-core

I'm looking on internet and try to find a **simple** way to do an authentification for my connection page with Angular using net core as my backend, I created a table user with microsoft sql server manager, did the connection between net core and the database and want to do a simple connection page without a registration (It's a website with only a few accounts), but every tutorials on internet seems to work with net core Identity when I just need to connect Angular services with the net core API to look if the username and the password matches in the database and then if yes return true or otherwise send an error message via the api...

Sorry if it's a basic question, I'm kinda new to net core and I have difficulties to understand everything from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think auth0 will be best for u.

they have good documentation for u to get started in [asp.net core](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi/01-authorization) and [angular](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login)
and their [free plan](https://auth0.com/pricing/) will be more than enough for u

using this u will not have to write identity code.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot brother, I'll take a look at this ! You're a life saver :D

Comment: Yup I'm doing it right now, but can I reach you on discord or somewhere because I have difficulties to understand, like I'm new with net core and I'm not sure how to do this and try to follow the documentation, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Do it in steps 
first asp.net core 
then angular 

https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-build-and-secure-web-apis-with-aspnet-core-3/#Securing-the-API-with-Auth0
then show what u have done 
bcs like this I don't know what is issue.